# rkhunter warns me about root.rules

Tags: security, chkrootkit, rkhunter

I run :

```
:~$ sudo rkhunter --checkall --report-warnings-only
```

One of the warnings I've got :

```
Warning: Suspicious file types found in /dev:
         /dev/.udev/rules.d/root.rules: ASCII text
```

and the `root.rules` contains :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{MAJOR}=="8", ENV{MINOR}=="1", SYMLINK+="root"
```

I would like to understand the meaning and role of those variables `SUBSYSTEM`, `ENV{MAJOR}` and `SYMLINK+` .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The line in question is a [`udev` rule](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html), which defines certain conditions used to identify the device which the rule is acting upon.

- `SUBSYSTEM` is a match key, which is matched against the subsystem of the device. In this case, the rule matches only devices from the `block` sysbsystem.
- `ENV` is key which may be used for both matching and assigning environment variables. In this case, the rule matches devices with the `MAJOR` variable previously declared to `8`, and the `MINOR` variable previously declared to `1`.
- `SYMLINK` is an assignment key, which containing a list of symbolic links which act as alternative names for the device node. Actions of the form `KEY+="value"` add to the actions that are executed, for instance in this case `SYMLINK+="root"` tells `udev` to create a symlink called `root` under the `/dev` directory, *in addition* to any other symlinks that are going to be created.

In other words, the above rule tells `udev` to create and additional symlink `/dev/root` for devices belonging to the `block` subsystem with [major device number](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition-Mass-Storage-Definitions-Naming-HOWTO/x183.html) `8` and [minor device number](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition-Mass-Storage-Definitions-Naming-HOWTO/x183.html) `1`, i.e. the root partition.

The file in question is created by the `mountall` file system mounting tool, and [unless it's world writable](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/591807), should not be an issue. `rkhunter` flags the file because of its type. To suppress the `rkhunter` warning, you can add a whitelist rule to `/etc/rkhunter.conf.local`:

```
ALLOWDEVFILE=/dev/.udev/rules.d/root.rules
```

Answer (score 3):

The udev rule creates a symbolic link to the blockdevice (`SUBSUSTEM=="block"`) with the information 8,1 (`ENV{MAJOR}=="8", ENV{MINOR}=="1"` The first partition on the first drive) in your setup. The link is named /dev/root with the `SYMLINK+="root"`, the plus sign tells that udev should not overwrite any previous links created to this device, but rather add one more link to it.

An other rule like this found in some form on many Linux systems is this one:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="DVD_Drive_USB2_10000E0008441C1E", SYMLINK+="cdrom"
```

This says that the blockdevice with the serialnumber DVD_Drive_USB2_10000E0008441C1E sould be symlinked to /dev/cdrom

I am not entirely sure why rkhunter complains about this, but it is properly due to the type of /dev/.udev/rules.d/root.rules not being a device or symbolic link, but rather a file. I don't think that this is dangerous.